# Aggregation operation on unnest array elements

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a stream with an array object in it. I want to identify max value among all the elements in the array and forward that max element.
Input:

```
{
    "name": "Dhruv"
    "ranks": [
        {
            "rank": 1
        },
        {
            "rank": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "Dhruv"
    "maxRank": 2
}
```

I tried unnest in select query itself, however it throws `This exception indicates that the query uses an unsupported SQL feature`

```
SELECT
  name,
  (
    select
      MAX(ranks.rank)
    from
      UNNEST(ranks)
  ) as maxRank,
from input_stream
```

I also tried CROSS JOIN UNNEST and then group by, however it failed since group by would cause large state to be maintained. I don't want to maintain state across other stream objects. I just need to transform the single object itself.

Comment: It does sound like the CROSS JOIN UNNEST and the GROUP BY is the best approach. You will either way end up with a large state, because MAX requires that all emitted values need to be stored in state, because there can be a future record with a higher MAX which needs to be emitted. But in order for that to happen, you need to keep all the values that previously were emitted as part of the MAX function

Comment: correct. I am not going ahead with that.

Comment: Then the only thing that you can do is write your own format implementation so you don't have to do the CROSS JOIN UNNEST. Keep in mind that you will still be required to keep all values for "name" and "maxRank" in state, unless you are willing to set a state TTL and accept that output might be incorrect after that TTL